# C# Linq contains, group by and order by

Tags: c#, linq

In my program I have a search method. 
I have two versions of it:

1. 1st version where I search for drawings with a drawing number in my database like normal.
2. 2nd version is the normal search plus the function to find only the newest objects with this drawingnumber in the database.

For both options I´m using the `CONTAINS` method.

For the normal search it works well but on the newest search, where it is combined with `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` I feel like there are many objects missing. 
I checked when I use the whole drawingnumber, so that the `CONTAINS` doesn´t need to work.

So for example when I just write 100 for the drawingnumber and using the normal search it finds all objects with the 100 - Thats fine. 
**However**, when I search for the newest objects with only the 100 it finds only a few.

When I use the whole number for the search it finds the newest objects for the right number. 
So is it bad anyways to use `CONTAINS` with all the sort- and order stuff or I´m just missing something there?

For better understanding, the drawingnumber there can be different extensions and doktypes. The `Dok_Count` is the count for the newest document where I´m looking for.

```
 var query =
                        from z in context.zeichnungs
                        where (zeichnungsnummer == "" || z.Zeichnungsnummer.Contains(zeichnungsnummer)) &&
                        (index == "" || index == z.Index) &&
                        (artikelbezeichnung == "" || artikelbezeichnung == z.Artikelbezeichnung) &&
                        (status == "" || status == z.Status) && (mmsSachmerkmal == "" || mmsSachmerkmal == z.MMS_Sachmerkmal) &&
                        (doktyp == "" || doktyp == z.Dokumententyp) && (dateiendung == "" || dateiendung == z.Dateiendung) &&
                        (z.Datum >= startDate.Date && z.Datum <= endDate.Date) && (status == "" || status == z.Status)
                        select z;
                        var sortQuery = query.GroupBy(x => new { x.Dokumententyp, x.Dateiendung }).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(record => record.Dok_Count).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to do database normal work with linq this is not it pourpose, use views, thanks for the vote.

Answer (score -1):

I think the data server do this with better performance than in .net  classes. Now, I think, you can do a sql profile (or trace) to catch what is the command that the process ask to the database, you will see that the contains its a where in method, in my opinion if you have a alternative way to do this, like join in database, would be better. In other hand, if the number of the records that return this query never will be under 1000, it's no matter, this is a good way.

Sorry for my English :D

Comment: I mean over 1000 records, not under

Comment: In the database are round about 7000 entries at the moment. This is the Selection-String with the contains:  WHERE (((((((((@gp1 = @p__linq__0) OR (`Extent1`.`Zeichnungsnummer` LIKE @p__linq__1))